# python astonishing IOError on windows creating files - Errno 13 Permission

Tags: python, windows, csv

I have to run my python script on windows too, and then it began the problems.

Here I'm scraping html locally saved files, and then saving their .csv versions with the data I want. I ran it on my ubuntu and goes for +100k files with no problems. But when I go on windows, it says:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

It is not a permissions problems, I've rechecked it, and run it under 'Administration' powers, and it makes no difference.

It breaks exactly on the line where I open the file:

`with open(of, 'w') as output:
     ...`

I've tried to create same first file of the 100k from the python console and from a new blank stupid script from same directory as my code, and it works...

So, it seems is doable.

Then I've tried with `output = open(of, 'w')` instead of above code but nothing.

The weird thing is that it creates a directory with same name as the file, and then breaks with the IOError.

I've started thinking that it could be a csv thing..., naaaeehh, apart from other tries that didn't helped me, the most interesting stuff is that with the following code:

`with open(of+`.txt`, 'w') as output:
     ...`

it happens the astonishing thing that it creates a directory ending on .csv AND a file ending in .csv.txt with the right data!

Aargh!

Changing the open mode file to 'w+', 'wb', it didn't make a difference either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it, it's already working!, it has been like saying i cannot find my glasses and to have them on.

THanks Brian, it wasn't that the error. The problem was that in my code i was dealing with ubuntu separator besides the full path to the csv output file was completely correct. But I replaced it with os.sep , and started working like a charm :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can get permission denied if the file is opened up in another application.

Follow this link to see if any other process is using it: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm

Otherwise, I would say to try to open the file for read instead of write to see if it allows you to access it at all.

-Brian